# Uploading Images using AsynTask not successful

Tags: java, android, upload, android-asynctask

I want to upload images on a Parse server using an AsnycTask. When I upload images without using AsyncTask I successfully upload and can retrieve images. I want to use AsyncTask because in my app two activities are using network permissions or if someone has another solution to do this please tell. Code of the Activity:

```
package com.example.faceb;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import com.parse.GetDataCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView image;
    TextView value;

    public Bitmap bm;
    public byte[] bitmapdata;
    public ByteArrayOutputStream data;
    String s =  "FileName";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);
    uploadTask task = new uploadTask();
    task.execute(s);

}

private class uploadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

      @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          image.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
         upload();
        return null;
    }

      }
 public void upload (){
 bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.back);
    data = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, data);
    bitmapdata = data.toByteArray();

    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("hai.png", bitmapdata);
    file.saveInBackground();

    ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
    testObject.put("puu", file);
    testObject.saveInBackground();      

  }
}
```

Following is my error logcat

> 10-12 01:10:46.944: E/ActivityThread(2233): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at com.example.faceb.ListActivity$uploadTask.onPostExecute(ListActivity.java:44)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at com.example.faceb.ListActivity$uploadTask.onPostExecute(ListActivity.java:1)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   10-12 01:11:07.604: E/AndroidRuntime(2233):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   10-12 01:11:09.014: E/ActivityThread(2274): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
>   10-12 01:48:14.084: E/ActivityThread(2313): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
>   10-12 01:48:45.323: E/ActivityThread(2334): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
>   10-12 03:19:06.184: E/ActivityThread(2371): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
>   10-12 03:19:31.614: E/ActivityThread(2393): Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider

Comment: Post your stack trace. Also post saveInBackground.

Comment: stack trace means logcat? And saveInBackground is method provided by parse server. its built in method not created by me. Also when i start this activity i returned to previous activity. Doing this without asynctask in a separate project everything works fine.

Comment: I don't know anything about facebook apis, but it looks like your problem comes from that. Specifically the inability to find whatever provider is needed for the apis to work. Try verifying your library links and refresh (clean) your project.

Comment: put this code to the end of the `onCreate` method: `image = this.findViewById(R.id.id_of_your_image_control);`;

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i dont think that it is the problem of image.

Answer (score 2):

Using `AsyncTask` has some limitations that aren't immediately obvious.  Its intention is to give developers an easy way to put a slow task in the background, but still allow the result to populate the UI.  However, depending on what version of Android you're on, the details of that can have drastic differences because in some versions, *all* `AsyncTask` subclasses in your application share the same thread.  In your case, I'm assuming you're listening on a port to receive images - and that you're using an `AsyncTask` to do it.  You've got a thread that's always running, always keeping *all* other `AsyncTask` threads in your app from running.

Instead, try using `Runnable` and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to get around it.

```
public class TCPClient implements Runnable {

Handler mHandler;
Object[] params;

public static void run(Handler handler, Object... params) {
    TCPClient instance = new TCPClient(handler, params);
    Thread worker = new Thread(instance);
    worker.start();
}

private TCPClient(Handler handler, Object... params) {
    this.params = params;
    mHandler = handler;
}


private void runOnUI(Object result) {
    if (mHandler != null) {
        final Object copy = result;

        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Update UI here
            }
        });
    }
}

public void run() {
  // Do slow/background task here
  //Then call
  runOnUI(new String("resulting data..."));
}
```

You can use this in a UI thread somewhere like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
  Handler handler = new Handler();
  TCPClient.run(handler, new String("Put outgoing data here...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your stacktrace, `onPostExecute` is throwing a `NullPointerException`.  From your code this must be because `image` is null.  You create the variable:

```
ImageView image;
```

but I can't see anywhere where you initialise it. Perhaps you are missing a `findViewById` call in `onCreate` to set it?

Comment: I corrected the point you mentioned but my problem is not solved. My problem is when this activity starts app returns automatically returns to the previous activity

Comment: So you got a `NullPointerException` before, what error do you get in the log now?

Comment: I think error is same as before I have updated the logcat. I have run my code without onPostExecute() but error is same it returns to previous activity

Comment: Have you tested to see if `image` is `null`?

Comment: thanks i have solved my problem there was some sdk's problem so i changed that in manifest and above code is working fine